# Get div input childs value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tryin to get the value from the three inputs containd on a group of divs but only th edivs  that doesn't belongs to `invisible-age-range-row`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 dist-element-row">
    <label>Franjas de edad</label>
    <div class="row age-range-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Desde</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from" value="1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Hasta</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to" value="2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>%</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage" value="20">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Desde</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from" value="3">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Hasta</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to" value="4">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>%</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage" value="5">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Desde</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Hasta</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>%</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Desde</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Hasta</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>%</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Desde</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Hasta</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>%</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Desde</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Hasta</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>%</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Desde</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Hasta</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>%</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Desde</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Hasta</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>%</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Desde</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Hasta</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>%</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Desde</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Hasta</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>%</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting the divs this way

```
var ranges = $('.age-range-row').not('.invisible-age-range-row');
```

but I can't access the input value this way :

```
ranges.each(function(range) {
    var elements = [];
    console.log(range);
    elements.push(range.find('.from'));
    elements.push(range.find('.to'));
    elements.push(range.find('.percentage'));
    stored_ranges.push(elements);
});
```

Comment: You did not mention anything about the errors. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First argument of each function refers to index of element. You need to use range as second element to use as element selector:

```
  ranges.each(function(index,range){
           var elements = [];
           console.log(range);
           elements.push(range.find('.from'));
           elements.push(range.find('.to'));
           elements.push(range.find('.percentage'));
           stored_ranges.push(elements);
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remember each has 2 parameter.

Use $(range) instead of range only.

```
    var ranges = $('.age-range-row').not('.invisible-age-range-row');
ranges.each(function(index, range){
               if(!$(this).hasClass('invisible-age-range-row')){
               var elements = [];
               console.log(range);
               elements.push($(range).find('.from'));
               elements.push($(range).find('.to'));
               elements.push($(range).find('.percentage'));
               //stored_ranges.push(elements);
               }
           });
```

```js
var ranges = $('.age-range-row').not('.invisible-age-range-row');
ranges.each(function(index, range){
               if(!$(this).hasClass('invisible-age-range-row')){
               var elements = [];
               console.log(range);
               elements.push($(range).find('.from'));
               elements.push($(range).find('.to'));
               elements.push($(range).find('.percentage'));
               //stored_ranges.push(elements);
               }
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 dist-element-row">
                <label>Franjas de edad</label>
                <div class="row age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from" value="1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to" value="2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage" value="20">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from" value="3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to" value="4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage" value="5">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Using `hasClass` is an overhead when you can already use filtered list using `not` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasClass`  to check if class `invisible-age-range-row` exist and `val()` to get input value,hope this helps

(or)
Using `not`

```
var ranges = $('.age-range-row').not('.invisible-age-range-row')
               ranges.each(function(e){
               var elements = [];
               elements.push($(this).find('.from').val());
```

```js
var ranges = $('.age-range-row');
var stored_ranges=[];
ranges.each(function(e){
               var elements = [];
               if(!$(this).hasClass('invisible-age-range-row')){
               elements.push($(this).find('.from').val());
               elements.push($(this).find('.to').val());
               elements.push($(this).find('.percentage').val());
               stored_ranges.push(elements);
               }
           });
           console.log(stored_ranges)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 dist-element-row">
                <label>Franjas de edad</label>
                <div class="row age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from" value="1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to" value="2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage" value="20">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from" value="3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to" value="4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage" value="5">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.age-range-row').not('.invisible-age-range-row').each(function(index, range){
               //if(!$(this).hasClass('invisible-age-range-row')){
               var elements = [];
               console.log(range);
               elements.push($(range).find('.from'));
               elements.push($(range).find('.to'));
               elements.push($(range).find('.percentage'));
               //stored_ranges.push(elements);
               //}
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 dist-element-row">
                <label>Franjas de edad</label>
                <div class="row age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from" value="1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to" value="2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage" value="20">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from" value="3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to" value="4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage" value="5">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="row age-range-row invisible-age-range-row"><div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control from">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>%</label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control percentage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 options-cell">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary add-range">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default delete-range">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```